# What tag should/could I use for underlined text?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, underline

First of all, I realize that styling in HTML should be handled by CSS, and I don't want to change that.

I just want a solid tag I can use for underline, a tag that is *meant* for underlined text, or one that makes sense to use as such. Then I can style it with CSS.

Now where is that tag?

Why is `strong`, `b`, `em`, `i` etc. perfectly fine (and often auto-styled in browsers), but underlined is the forbidden fruit?

I would hate to write

```
<span style="blabla: underline">some underlined text</span>
OR <span class="underlined">some text</span>
```

when I can just use

```
<u>hello</u>
```

and style it?

Comment: Without further context, `<u>` is the closest match. Knowing what meaning underline has would really help (for instance, MDN mentions [Chinese proper names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u) as usage example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `u` element was meant for underlining, ever since [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#font-style). HTML 4.01 frowns upon it by “deprecating” it, and HTML5 proposes to redefine its meaning in an obscure manner. Yet, in reality, it works in all browsers, and will keep working, and has the exact effect of underlining.

Whether you should underline anything but links on web pages is a different issue. So is the question whether you should think in terms of logical structure rather than visual rendering.

Comment: I have now removed the possibility of making underlines in my CMS editor. I understand it a little bit better now.. Emphasis and  Strong is enough

Comment: There is confusion of the 'u' element as W3C say the reason they introduced it was because styling should be handled by CSS, yet that statement is contradicted by tags like 'strong' still existing.

Answer (score 1):

Underlining text is generally a bad idea because it should be exclusively reserved for links. Users just generally expect to be able to clock on underlined text and have something happen.

That said, there is one main exception I can think of:

```
Price: <del>£12.34</del> <ins>£9.87</ins>!
```

Most, if not all browsers will render the new price there with an underline, and people will understand it to be an insertion.

Comment: Well, I think it depends greatly on the website's design of links vs. underlined.. On my site, the two things are completely different and could never be mistaken. The markup standards are often confused and far from always logical. This is not 1998

Comment: No, it not depends. This is the best and most accurate answer here. Removing `<u>` tag from HTML has a clear explanation, given here: it was removed, because user shouldn't be encouraged to use underline for anything else than links (and some rare, specific situations mentioned here in comments, like proper names in Chinese). End. Period. That's a whole story: do **not** use underlined text, anywhere in your page, no matter, what design you have, because it is too easy confused with links. Letting your user miss underlined text with links is the best way to loose visitors and rank. Amen.

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole issue is better approached if we try to understand what the HTML spec writers are trying to accomplish.

On the early days, HTML was basically the only tool to create hypertext documents so it tried to provide all the necessary stuff. As the web grew up it soon become obvious that this all-in-one solution did not scale. Mixing content and presentation didn't provide full control on either. So two steps were taken:

- A new language was created to take care of visuals
- HTML itself was cleaned up to focus on content definition

The problem with underline is that it doesn't really have any meaning by itself. It will have a meaning if you assign it one in your app context (you can decide, for instance, that underline text will be used for book authors in your on-line library catalogue). So when the guys at W3C created HTML tags for several content types (titles, abbreviations, dates...) they simply didn't consider underlining: it was deliberately outside the language scope. There's no HTML tag for "underline" for the same reason that there's no tag for "red circle" or "uppercase Comic-Sans text".

Of course, in fact there is a `<u>` tag but underline is only a serving suggestion because the important part is the semantics—like printing `<h1>` with a large font.

Comment: Well, underlined is really just a variation of emphasis. Why can there only be one? But I'm thinking about it.. and getting closer to ditch the underline and just go with strong and em

Comment: You can emphasize with a border but that doesn't make borders a variation of emphasis. Underline has many non-emphasis usages, from links in an HTML document to Chinese proper names. I insist: your site can have a legitimate usage for underline itself but it'll always represent something else: that's what you have to consider when choosing a tag, the actual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It is not forbidden , but a better practice not to use it ,as underline tag is deprecated in HTML 4 http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-U so won't validate.

Comment: Deprecated is not the same as removed.

Comment: I did not say it is removed , nor did i say that it should not be used .

Comment: I think what I'm trying to get answered.. is, what tag should I use to just emphasize that word? Not by style, but just a tag that makes sense semantically.. Like <strong>

Comment: <em></em> is what i generally use and then style it with css.

Comment: @Golu I use that for italic. Maybe I should use B for underlines and style as that

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really explain myself. Whether a deprecated HTML 4 tag will validate or not depends on the DTD: Transitional DTD includes deprecated tags, Strict doesn't. Of course, in HTML5 `<u>` is no longer deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Underline an element is more a style quetion. So, it's better to give a class like "underline_style" and in the CSS give the correct rules.

Comment: A style question as much as the accepted auto-styled tag <strong>?

Comment: Tell me... What exactly is the difference between `<u></u>` and `<span class="omg_underline_me_plz"></span>`?

Comment: <strong>, <em> have a semantic meaning where <u> seems to have not or at least none recognise such as em or strong does. Underline is basicly used to show links within text-flow. The use of em or strong reset to underline might be a good choice if the purpose is to 'emphase' some text ...

Answer (score 0):

The `u` element you can still use for underlining but because it's more complex than `b`, `i`,`strong` and `em` you will need CSS to style it in detail. Underline has style and color property which is not the case with other mentioned elements. You have more on this topic [here](https://kolosek.com/css-text-underlined/).